# How can I determine if an automated login worked on the WebBrowser control?

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I'm using a WebBrowser control to determine if a list of sites are using their factory default username and passwords. However, I'm running into trouble as DocumentCompleted that I'm using to simulate the login is also being called once the login in completed.

Additionally, when it does work, it loops and false reports that several other sites have the default login.

I've noticed these issues and cant wrap my head around it this afternoon. Not sure if it's because I'm tired or the guy on the other side of my cubical singing every other word of some new band he likes.

If nothing else, sometimes it helps me to type everything out and read it the next day and maybe my somewhat working source can help someone else down the road.

Issues:

- False positives following actual site using default credentials
- Stops processing when a page 404s or loads an unexpected page

Code:

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    WebBrowser.Navigate(linqData(i).URL)

End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted

    ' Check for Default Login
    Login("administrator", "password")

    ' Determine Results
    If WebBrowser.Url.ToString.Contains("index.php") Then
        ' Successfully Logged In
        LogData("Successfully Logged In to " & linqData(i).Name)
        NextSite()
    ElseIf WebBrowser.Url.ToString.Contains("loginfailed.php") Then
        ' Failed to Login
        NextSite()
    End If

End Sub

Sub Login(Username As String, Password As String)
    Dim FoundUsernameTextbox As Boolean = False
    Dim FoundPasswordTextbox As Boolean = False

    Try
        ' Find Username Textbox
        Try
            WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("nameInput").InnerText = Username
            FoundUsernameTextbox = True
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        ' Find Password Textbox
        Try
            WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("pass").InnerText = Password
            FoundPasswordTextbox = True
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        ' Find Login Button and Click
        Try
            If FoundUsernameTextbox And FoundPasswordTextbox Then
                WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("submit").InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Sub NextSite()

    Try

        i += 1

        If i < linqDataRecordCount Then
            WebBrowser.Navigate(linqData(i).URL)
        Else
            LogData("Finished at " & DateTime.Now)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DocumentCompleted you should check if the event url is the browser's target url. This ensures that the code is called once, after the page is fully loaded.

Furthermore, you're calling Login but then proceed with code that deals with the browser again. This could cause unwanted behavior. You should instead have an Else and try the Login there.

```
If e.Url = WebBrowser.Url Then    
    ' Determine Results
    If WebBrowser.Url.ToString.Contains("index.php") Then
        ' Successfully Logged In
        LogData("Successfully Logged In to " & linqData(i).Name)
        NextSite()
    ElseIf WebBrowser.Url.ToString.Contains("loginfailed.php") Then
        ' Failed to Login
        NextSite()
    Else
        Login("administrator", "password")
    End If
End If
```

It would also be a good idea to make Login a boolean function. If it fails to find the login elements to invoke, return false and either try again or go to the next site.